# Windows explorer displays application path instead of file type

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-extension, file-types

Windows explorer in Type columns sometime displays Type name like: "XXX File", sometime displays associated application name like "Adobe Acrobat Document", and for some application it displays full path to application that is associated with file extension like "C:\Program Files...\YYY.exe".

How to fix things for case where full application path is displayed to show just name, not whole path?

Or alternatively, how to reset all to just show file type name, not associated program name?

Comment: Is it just one specific file-type that is showing the full path?

Comment: @RandolphWest For now yes, and I want to solve this case, but am also interested how to fix this in more general way if possible.

Comment: If it's just one file type, shift + right click on one of the files, choose Open With, change it to Notepad (for example), then repeat the process with the correct application. See if that fixes it.

Comment: @RandolphWest Didn't help.

Comment: Could you tell us which filetype? That might have something to do with it. There's a possibility the registration for the application is borked, which means editing the registry, but that's risky.

Comment: @RandolphWest This was my custom type opened by small app. I have changed default value in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\YYY_auto_file (which value was path to file) to empty string and now I have wanted behavior. I hoped there is nicer way for this but... Do you know why this happened? What needs to be done with application so that registration works better. I have many custom types and custom apps so general fix would be nice.

Comment: It looks like you need to somehow have a text description in the GUID branch under CLSID in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. I'm guessing though.

Answer (score 1):

Get a free tool called [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html).

Find the concerned filetype in that tool and edit `Description` for that file type.
This should probably fix your problem.